# how to protect routes in react? Need to authenticate if admin logged in

Tags: reactjs

I created protected.route.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { isAuthenticated } from "./function";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={
                (props) => {
                    if (isAuthenticated) {
                     return <Component {...props}/>
                 } else {
                    return <Redirect to={
                       {
                           pathname: "/admin",
                           state: {
                               from: props.location
                          }
                       }
                   }/>
               }
           }
       }/>
   )
}
```

functions.js have isAuthenticated function that return boolean value

```
let authenticated = false;
export const loginUser = user => {
    return axios.post("/users/login", {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
   })
    .then(res => {
        authenticated = true;
    .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
}

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
   return authenticated
}
```

And in my login jsx file, I have handlesubmit

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isValid = this.validate();
    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    loginUser(user).then(res => { 
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/men');
        }
    })
  }
}
```

In my App.js

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/dash" component={DashBoard}/>
```

The route didn't protect even I'm not logged in I can view that route

Comment: Looks like you want to do `if (isAuthenticated())` since it's a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In protected.route.js I created const variable and assign isAuthenticated return value to it and checked in my condition

```
    const auth = isAuthenticated();
    if (auth) {
      return <Component {...props}/>
    }
```